# Tkinter Canvas is not showing

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, countdown

So I was trying to make a countdown in python using tkinter, but somehow the canvas windows is not showing... I don't really know why, can anyone help me?

```
import tkinter
import random
import time
canvas=tkinter.Canvas(height=350,width=400,)
canvas.pack()

t=10

def c():
    global t
    while t>=0:
        if t == 0:
            canvas.create_text(100,10, text="YOU LOST!")


        else:
            time.sleep(1)        
            t-=1
            canvas.create_text(50,50, text=t, font="Aria 25", fill="red")
            print(t)            

c()
```

Comment: Read [Is this bad programming practice in tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25454433/7414759)
follow the pattern of **Alternative to the main classmethod:**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is you never call the `mainloop()` method, which is necessary in all `tkinter` application because it's what makes the GUI function.

In addition, you should never call `time.sleep()` in a `tkinter` application because it interferes with `mainloop()` and will cause your program to "hang".

To overcome these restrictions, you can use the universal `after()` method that all widgets have. Here's some [documentation](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html) about it.

Note how the `c()` function no longer contains a `while` loop. Instead it calls `after()` itself and passes itself to it as the function to be called after the delay — this keeps things going until the count reaches zero.

To make things more efficient, I also modified your code so it only creates one `Canvas` text object and then updates it afterwards. This prevents creation of a bunch of `Canvas` text objects from piling-up on top of one another that are no longer needed.

```
import tkinter

canvas = tkinter.Canvas(height=350,width=400,)
canvas.pack()

DELAY = 1000  # milliseconds.
t = 10
text_obj_id = None

def c():
    global t
    global text_obj_id

    if t >= 0:
        if t == 0:
            canvas.create_text(100, 10, text="YOU LOST!")
        else:
            t -= 1

            if text_obj_id is None:  # First time?
                text_obj_id = canvas.create_text(50, 50, text=t, font="Aria 25",
                                                 fill="red")
            else:  # Update existing Canvas text object.
                canvas.itemconfigure(text_obj_id, text=t)

            print(t)

            canvas.after(DELAY, c)  # call again in 1000 ms.

c()  # Starts repeated calling of function.
canvas.mainloop()
```