# ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 2 elements, new values have 1 elements

Tags: python, pandas, exception

I am trying to create a GUI for my code here.
It basically gets a folder location from the user that contains a bunch of excel files. It then extracts and compiles the data from all those files into a format I need and writes it to an output excel file.

The code as such was doing the job until I decided to use Tkinter for GUI hoping to learn how to use Tkinter in the process.

I tried to define a class with all the different functions that do my data wrangling.

But looks like none of the functions are able to call one another nor the variables and I keep getting weird errors like the one below.

```
import pandas as pd
import os
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox
import tkinter.filedialog

class specomp:
def __init__(self,master):
    frame=Frame(master)
    frame.pack()

    self.printButton=Button(frame,text="Select folder",command=self.set_thisdir)
    self.printButton.pack(side=LEFT)

    self.quitButton=Button(frame,text="Quit",command=master.destroy)
    self.quitButton.pack(side=LEFT)

    self.exButton=Button(frame,text="Execute",command=self.myprog)
    self.exButton.pack(side=LEFT)

def set_thisdir(self):
    global thisdir
    thisdir= filedialog.askdirectory(initialdir=os.getcwd(),title='Please select the folder where you saved Spectrometer excel files')


def fsheet_DCOP(j,k,l):
    #from the input frame j it returns the column that matches DCOP name in list k in column 5 and parameter name l in column 7
    ret=pd.DataFrame([])
    for i in k:
        ret=ret.append(j[j[5] == i])
    ret=ret[ret[7]==l]
    return ret

def fsheet_Table(j,k):
    #transforms the raw output of above function into final table for every file, with same column name etc.
    j=j.transpose()
    j=j[5:]
    j.columns=[k]
    j=j.transpose()
    ret=wfrpair.append(j)
    ret=ret.iloc[:,5:30]
    ret = ret.transpose()
    return ret

def fin_col_ren(j,k):
    #after all files input has been appended, this function renames all the columns, and adds the Inline parameter name to the data column
    j.columns=['MEMS Lot ID','MEMS Wfr ID','MEMBRANE Lot ID','MEMBRANE Wfr ID','TSV Lot ID','TSV Wfr ID',k]
    return j

def myprog(self):
    os.chdir(thisdir)
    print("You have following files in the target folder:\n")
    msg="You have following files in the target folder:\n"

    for i in os.listdir(os.chdir(thisdir)):
        print (i,'\n')
        msg=msg+"\n"+i
    msg=msg+"\n"
    tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Spectrometer File Compiler", msg)


    input("Press Enter to continue...")    
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(r'C:\Users\spoikayi\f_output.xlsx')
    spedf = pd.DataFrame([])
    pairingdf2=pd.DataFrame([])

    M32FinCDsheet=pd.DataFrame([])
    M32DICDsheet=pd.DataFrame([])
    TSVFinCDsheet=pd.DataFrame([])
    for i in os.listdir(os.chdir(thisdir)):
        fullsheet = pd.read_excel(i, sheet_name='Sheet1')
        fsheet = pd.read_excel(i, sheet_name='Sheet1',header=None)
        fsheet=fsheet.drop([0,1,2,3,4,5],axis=0)
        fsheet=fsheet.drop(columns=[0,1,2,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,42,43])
        wfrpair=fsheet.iloc[0:6]
        pairing=fullsheet.iloc[5:11,17:39]
        spe=fullsheet.iloc[[5,6,7,8,9,10,11,14,15,16,17,18,19,20],[17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39]]
        pairing=pairing.transpose()
        spe=spe.transpose()
        spedf=spedf.append(spe)
        pairingdf2=pairingdf2.append(pairing)


        df1y632=fsheet_DCOP(fsheet,['1Y632'],'Moyenne tr CD Finale-Item')
        dfTSV=fsheet_DCOP(fsheet,['1L417','1V417'],'Moyenne tr CD Finale-Item')
        M32data=fsheet_Table(df1y632,'M32_Fin_CD')
        TSVCDdata=fsheet_Table(dfTSV,'TSV_CD')
        M32FinCDsheet=M32FinCDsheet.append(M32data)
        TSVFinCDsheet=TSVFinCDsheet.append(TSVCDdata)



    spedf=spedf.drop(columns=[11,20])
    spedf.columns=['MEMS Lot ID','MEMS Wfr ID','MEMBRANE Lot ID','MEMBRANE Wfr ID','TSV Lot ID','TSV Wfr ID','VERTICAL GAP HEIGHT (M34)','MEMBRANE THICKNESS','SI GAP WIDTH (M32 FIN)','MEMBRANE TO ELECTRODE GAP','TOP CAVITY DEPTH (M94)','CONTACT ANGLE OF FOTS COATING']
    pairingdf2.columns=['MEMS Lot ID','MEMS Wfr ID','MEMBRANE Lot ID','MEMBRANE Wfr ID','TSV Lot ID','TSV Wfr ID']

    M32FinCDsheet=fin_col_ren(M32FinCDsheet,'M32 Fin CD 1Y632')
    TSVFinCDsheet=fin_col_ren(TSVFinCDsheet,'TSV Fin CD')

    pairingdf2.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='Pairing')
    spedf.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='SPE')
    M32FinCDsheet.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='M32 Fin CD 1Y632')
    TSVFinCDsheet.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='TSV Fin CD')

    writer.save()
    tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Spectrometer File Compiler", "Compilation Complete! \nPlease Check output file.")
    return

root= tkinter.Tk()
b=specomp(root)
root.mainloop()
```

At first I had errors like thisdir was not defined, so I made it a global variable.

This is the error I am getting now:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\spoikayi\Documents\Portables\Anaconda\anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1702, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/spoikayi/.spyder-py3/Spectrometer_Compiler_GUI.py", line 100, in myprog
    M32data=fsheet_Table(df1y632,'M32_Fin_CD')
  File "C:/Users/spoikayi/.spyder-py3/Spectrometer_Compiler_GUI.py", line 45, in fsheet_Table
    j.columns=[k]
  File "C:\Users\spoikayi\Documents\Portables\Anaconda\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 4389, in __setattr__
    return object.__setattr__(self, name, value)
  File "pandas\_libs\properties.pyx", line 69, in pandas._libs.properties.AxisProperty.__set__
  File "C:\Users\spoikayi\Documents\Portables\Anaconda\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 646, in _set_axis
    self._data.set_axis(axis, labels)
  File "C:\Users\spoikayi\Documents\Portables\Anaconda\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 3323, in set_axis
    'values have {new} elements'.format(old=old_len, new=new_len))
ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 2 elements, new values have 1 elements
```

Comment: I'm guessing all of your functions are part of the class? Because some of your functions are missing the "self" keyword in the parameters (fsheet_DCOP, fin_col_ren, fsheet_Table)

Comment: Read [Is this bad programming practice in tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25454433/7414759)
follow the pattern of **Alternative to the main classmethod:**

Comment: Thanks guys , @stovfl Cribber. However I decided to use PyQt5 now, which looks much better.