# Tkinter GUI has inputs however database is empty when I add the variables in

Tags: python, tkinter, sqlite

I am creating a car parts organization system and as part of the program I am adding a customer information section. This section previously worked, however, now I have added a main menu and the program doesn't add anything to the database except three {},{},{} when there should be data

I have tried changing variable names and using global variables but i still get the same errors

```
from tkinter import *
import DATABASE1

def get_selected_row(event):
    global selected_tuple
    index = listbox.curselection()[0]
    selected_tuple=listbox.get(index)
    Entry1.delete(0,END)
    Entry1.insert(END,selected_tuple[1])
    Entry2.delete(0,END)
    Entry2.insert(END,selected_tuple[2])
    Entry3.delete(0,END)
    Entry3.insert(END,selected_tuple[3])

def View_Command():
    listbox.delete(0,END)
    for row in DATABASE1.View():
        listbox.insert(END,row)

def Add_Command():
    DATABASE1.Insert(FirstName.get(),LastName.get(),PhoneNum.get())
    listbox.delete(0,END)
    listbox.insert(END,(FirstName.get(),LastName.get(),PhoneNum.get()))
    View_Command()

def Delete_Command():
    DATABASE1.Delete((selected_tuple[0]))
    View_Command()

def Update_Command():
```

DATABASE1.Update(selected_tuple[0],FirstName.get(),LastName.get(),PhoneNum.get())
        View_Command()

```
def OpenCustomerInfo():
    global listbox
    global FirstName
    global LastName
    global PhoneNum
    global index
    global Entry1
    global Entry2
    global Entry3
    global scroll

    CustomerInfo = Tk()
    CustomerInfo.title("Customer Information")
    CustomerInfo.iconbitmap(r'favicon.ico')

    Label1 = Label(CustomerInfo,text="Customer Forename")
    Label1.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

    Label2 = Label(CustomerInfo,text="Customer Surname")
    Label2.grid(row = 1, column = 0)

    Label3 = Label(CustomerInfo,text="Phone Number")
    Label3.grid(row = 2, column = 0)

    FirstName = StringVar()
    Entry1 = Entry(CustomerInfo,textvariable=FirstName)
    Entry1.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

    LastName = StringVar()
    Entry2 = Entry(CustomerInfo,textvariable=LastName)
    Entry2.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

    PhoneNum = StringVar()
    Entry3 = Entry(CustomerInfo,textvariable=PhoneNum)
    Entry3.grid(row = 2, column = 1)

    listbox = Listbox(CustomerInfo, height=20,width=50)
    listbox.grid(row = 0, column = 4, rowspan = 6, columnspan = 2)

    scroll=Scrollbar(CustomerInfo)
    scroll.grid(row = 0, column = 2, sticky = NS, rowspan=8)

    listbox.configure(yscrollcommand=scroll.set)
    scroll.configure(command=Listbox.yview)

    listbox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>',get_selected_row)

    b1 = Button(CustomerInfo, text = "Add To Database", width = 17, command = Add_Command)
    b1.grid(row = 3, column = 0, sticky = S)

    b2 = Button(CustomerInfo, text = "Delete From Database", width = 17, command = Delete_Command)
    b2.grid(row = 4, column = 0, sticky = N)

    b3 = Button(CustomerInfo, text = "Update Database", width = 17, command = Update_Command)
    b3.grid(row = 3, column = 1, sticky = S)

    b4 = Button(CustomerInfo, text = "View Database", width = 17, command = View_Command)
    b4.grid(row = 4, column = 1, sticky = N)

def MainMenu():
    MainMenu = Tk()
    MainMenu.title("Main Menu")
    Label1 = Label(MainMenu, text = "Main Menu")
    Label1.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
    Button1 = Button(MainMenu, text = "Open Customer Information Page",command = OpenCustomerInfo)
    Button1.grid(row = 1, column = 0)

MainMenu()
```

And this is my database file.

```
import sqlite3

def Connect():
    connection = sqlite3.connect("Customers.db")
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Customers (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, FIRSTNAME VARCHAR(15), LASTNAME VARCHAR(15), PHONENUM INTEGER)")
    connection.commit()
    connection.close()

def Insert(FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME,PHONENUM):
    connection = sqlite3.connect("Customers.db")
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Customers VALUES(NULL,?,?,?)",(FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME,PHONENUM,))
    connection.commit()
    connection.close()
    View()

def View():
    connection = sqlite3.connect("Customers.db")
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Customers")
    row = cursor.fetchall()
    connection.close()
    return row

def Delete(ID):
    connection = sqlite3.connect("Customers.db")
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("DELETE FROM Customers WHERE ID=?",(ID,))
    connection.commit()
    connection.close()

def Update(ID,FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME,PHONENUM):
    connection = sqlite3.connect("Customers.db")
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("UPDATE Customers SET FIRSTNAME = ? , LASTNAME = ? , PHONENUM = ? WHERE ID = ?",(FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME,PHONENUM,ID))    
    connection.commit()
    connection.close()

Connect()
```

When the input is taken from the entry boxes in the GUI it should add the data into the database and then show the updated database, but instead adds three empty elements like so {},{},{}

Comment: This is too much code for a question. Can you please try to condense it down to a [mcve]? Also, have you verified that your variables contain the data you expect them to immediately before writing to the database?

Comment: You got probably confused by using `global`. Read [Is this bad programming practice in tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25454433/7414759)
follow the pattern of **Alternative to the main classmethod**

Comment: After checking the code running it on its own without being in the main menu means it works properly however as soon as the customer info page is opened with the main menu it doesnt work instead it adds empty variables into the database