# Unable to enter input in Entry box on first loading after initializing Database?

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite, tkinter

I wrote a Python GUI program with tkinker that reads lines from a text file into a database. The user is able to add or delete entries into the database by entering the details into the GUI entry box and pressing a button. However, when I run the code, I cannot key in anything into the Entry boxes on the first try i.e. the box is solid, cannot key in anything.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from tkinter import StringVar
from tkinter import messagebox
import sqlite3
import os

window = tk.Tk() 

#Food Name label
labelName=ttk.Label(window,text="Name")
txtName=StringVar()
textName=ttk.Entry(window,textvariable=txtName)

#Food Category label
labelCategory=ttk.Label(window,text="Category")
txtCategory=StringVar()
textCategory=ttk.Entry(window,textvariable=txtCategory)

#Initialize Database
def initDatabase():
    file=open("foodList.txt")
    lines=file.readlines()

    conn=sqlite3.connect('foodDatabase.db')
    sql="create table food(name text primary key, category text)"
    conn.execute(sql)
    conn.commit()

    for line in lines:
        line=line.replace("\n","")
        cols=line.split(",")
        name=cols[0]
        category=cols[1]
        sql="insert into food(name,category) values(?,?)"
        conn.execute(sql,(name,category))

    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
    messagebox.showinfo("Success", "Database Initialized!")

if not os.path.exists("foodDatabase.db"): 
    initDatabase()

#Buttons for Insert & Delete
def insertData():
    conn=sqlite3.connect('foodDatabase.db')
    sql="insert into food(name,category) values(?,?)"
    conn.execute(sql,(txtName.get(),txtCategory.get()))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
    messagebox.showinfo("Success", "Insert Successful!")

def deleteData(name):
    conn=sqlite3.connect('foodDatabase.db')
    sql="delete from food where name=?"
    conn.execute(sql,(txtName.get(),))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
    messagebox.showinfo("Success","Delete Successful!")

#Insert BUtton
buttonInsert=ttk.Button(window,text='Insert',command=insertData)

#Delete Button
buttonDelete=ttk.Button(window,text='Delete',command=deleteData)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Comments are for others questioning for further detail and such, please just press the edit button under your question if you made a mistake, or wish to add more, etc.

Comment: Also, do you get any errors? If yes, please include them in your question as well.

Comment: @Lafexlos Hi there, I've edited my code in my question. Nope I don't get any errors, I just can't key in anything in the entry boxes when the database is initialized. If the database file is already in the folder though, I don't encounter any issue.

Comment: The most important thing is, you are not using any geometry manager(pack, grid or place). How do you even see your widgets right now? Which IDE are you using?

Comment: @Lafexlos I think something is wrong with where I'm placing the "messagebox.showinfo"  code.. but I can't get it to work. The .txt is as simple as "123, xyz (next line) 234, abc (next line)" etc.

Comment: @audrey_ You should give us some more code where we can see the whole scenario regarding the problem. With the code you gave I can run program and write in Entry boxes normally.

Comment: @audrey_: **" I just can't key in anything in the entry boxes when the database is initialized." You mean, as long as `initDatabase()` are running, you didn't see any widgets?

Comment: @stovfl When my folder has the foodDatabase.db in existence, the code runs as per normal. However, when I delete the foodDatabase.db file from the folder and run this code, the GUI app doesn't allow any typing into the boxes (i.e. the boxes are greyed out and cursor cant type inside). When the foodDatabase.db file is not in the folder, I expect the code to create a foodDatabase.db with a pop-up message saying "Database initialized", and I can continue to type into the GUI boxes to either insert or delete data. Hope that clarifies my issue!

Comment: @audrey_: Read [Is this bad programming practice in tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25454065/is-this-bad-programming-practice-in-tkinter) and [Event-Driven Programming](http://eventdrivenpgm.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: @Lafexlos I omitted the grid in my code above for simplicity. I'm using Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 0):

ttk.Label should be tk.Label.

I include a working example based in yours:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo
import sqlite3
import os


#Initialize Database
def initDatabase():
    file=open("foodList.txt")
    lines=file.readlines()

    conn=sqlite3.connect('foodDatabase.db')
    sql="create table food(name text primary key, category text)"
    conn.execute(sql)
    conn.commit()

    for line in lines:
        line=line.replace("\n","")
        cols=line.split(",")
        name=cols[0]
        category=cols[1]
        sql="insert into food(name,category) values('{0}','{1}')".format(name,category)
        conn.execute(sql)

    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
    showinfo("Success", "Database Initialized!")

def main():
    window = Tk() 

    window.title("Welcome to test app")
    # window.geometry('350x200')

    if not os.path.exists("foodDatabase.db"): 
        initDatabase()

    #Food Name label
    nombre = StringVar()
    labelName=Label(window,text="Name").grid(row=0)
    textName=Entry(window,textvariable=nombre).grid(row=0, column=1)

    #Food Category label
    categoria = StringVar()
    labelCategory=Label(window,text="Category").grid(row=1)
    textCategory=Entry(window, textvariable=categoria).grid(row=1, column=1)

    res_name = StringVar()
    res_category = StringVar()
    textRes_name = Label(window, textvariable=res_name).grid(row=5,column=0)
    textRes_category = Label(window, textvariable=res_category).grid(row=5,column=1)


    #Buttons for Insert & Delete
    def insertData():
        conn=sqlite3.connect('foodDatabase.db')
        sql="insert into food(name,category) values('{0}','{1}')".format(nombre.get(),categoria.get())
        conn.execute(sql)
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
        showinfo("Success", "Insert Successful!")
        nombre.set('')
        categoria.set('')
        showData()

    def deleteData():
        conn=sqlite3.connect('foodDatabase.db')
        sql="delete from food where name='{0}'".format(nombre.get())
        conn.execute(sql)
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
        showinfo("Success","Delete Successful!")
        nombre.set('')
        categoria.set('')
        showData()

    def showData():
        conn=sqlite3.connect('foodDatabase.db')
        sql="select * from food"
        q = conn.execute(sql)
        rows = q.fetchall()

        result_name = ["name"]
        result_category = ["category"]
        for row in rows:
            result_name.append(row[0])
            result_category.append(row[1])

        res_name.set("\n".join(result_name))
        res_category.set("\n".join(result_category))


        conn.commit()
        conn.close()

    #Insert Button
    buttonInsert = Button(window,text='Insert',command=insertData).grid(row=3, column=0, pady=4)

    #Delete Button
    buttonDelete = Button(window,text='Delete',command=deleteData).grid(row=3, column=1, pady=4)

    #Show list Button
    # buttonShow = Button(window,text='Show',command=showData).grid(row=3, column=2, pady=4)
    showData()
    window.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```