# Counter misbehaving in Python

Tags: python, tkinter

I am new to programming, barely have a few months of learning. I am trying to build a simple app to count the time I put into learning.

I am using a Tkinter Stopwatch app I found here: "https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/create-stopwatch-using-python/"
I modified it slightly for some experimenting and QoL changes.

My idea is to add an "Agenda" button where I can see the total time(different sessions) I put in.
"Reset" counts as a different learning session.

ISSUE/QUESTION: "Agenda" returns weird numbers, not related to the total number of seconds registered in two sessions.

```
import tkinter as Tkinter

counter = 0
running = False
total = 0



def counter_label(label):
    def count():
        if running:
            global counter
            global total

            # To manage the intial delay.
            if counter == 0:
                display = "Starting..."
            else:
                display = str(counter)

            label['text'] = display  # Or label.config(text=display)

            # label.after(arg1, arg2) delays by
            # first argument given in milliseconds
            # and then calls the function given as second argument.
            # Generally like here we need to call the
            # function in which it is present repeatedly.
            # Delays by 1000ms=1 seconds and call count again.
            label.after(1000, count)
            counter += 1
            session = counter
            total = session + session

    # Triggering the start of the counter.
    count()


def total_count():
    global total
    display = str(total)
    label['text'] = display


# start function of the stopwatch
def Start(label):
    global running
    running = True
    counter_label(label)
    start['state'] = 'disabled'
    stop['state'] = 'normal'
    reset['state'] = 'normal'


# Stop function of the stopwatch
def Stop():
    global running
    start['state'] = 'normal'
    stop['state'] = 'disabled'
    reset['state'] = 'normal'
    running = False

    if running == False:
        start['text'] = 'Resume'


# Reset function of the stopwatch
def Reset(label):
    global counter
    counter = 0

    # If rest is pressed after pressing stop.
    if running == False:
        reset['state'] = 'disabled'
        label['text'] = 'Welcome!'
        start['text'] = 'Start'

    # If reset is pressed while the stopwatch is running.
    else:
        label['text'] = 'Starting...'


def Agenda():
    global total

    start['state'] = 'normal'
    stop['state'] = 'normal'
    reset['state'] = 'normal'

    global total
    display = str(total)
    label['text'] = display


root = Tkinter.Tk()
root.title("Stopwatch")

# Fixing the window size.
root.minsize(width=250, height=70)
label = Tkinter.Label(root, text="Welcome!", fg="black", font="Verdana 30 bold")
label.pack()
start = Tkinter.Button(root, text='Start',
                       width=15, command=lambda: Start(label))
stop = Tkinter.Button(root, text='Stop',
                      width=15, state='disabled', command=Stop)
reset = Tkinter.Button(root, text='Reset',
                       width=15, state='disabled', command=lambda: Reset(label))
agenda = Tkinter.Button(root, text='Agenda', width=15, command=Agenda)

start.pack()
stop.pack()
reset.pack()
agenda.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This `total = session + session` makes on sense, **why** do you **double** the `counter` value? Read [Is this bad programming practice in tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25454065/is-this-bad-programming-practice-in-tkinter)

Comment: Initially "Agenda" was returning very odd numbers, for 5 seconds of counter I was getting numbers 26 or 33. Then I thought to only record 2 sessions to see if it even works correctly. For 5 seconds it's returning "6", and for 2 sessions of 5 seconds each it is returning "12". So one extra second on both.

Edit: thanks for the link, I'll have a look

Comment: Using `.after(1000, ...` does not guarantee execution exact every `1000 ms`. It gets delayed on other events like *mouse, keyboard, etc.*.

Comment: I will look into that, thanks. The base code is not mine, as I said it was taken off a website, all credit goes to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, your agenda button displays something like this: `agenda = (last_session_duration +1) * 2`. The problem is within this piece of code:

```
counter += 1
session = counter
total = session + session
```

Here you increment your counter before saving your values to total and for some reason you also use last_session_duration twice.

If you change this part to this, you'll get the duration of last session:

```
session = counter
total = session
counter += 1
```

Anyway, you may want to play around more to get the total to display the total time.