# SQlite error: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type

Tags: python, tkinter, sqlite, event-driven

Trying to create a function that will display a new screen to register a new cashier by adding the variables, `username1` and `password1` to the database but keep getting

> ```
> sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.
> ```

can anyone please advise where i am going wrong? 
Many Thanks

```
def register():
    username = StringVar()
    password = StringVar()
    global Home
    root.withdraw()
    Home = Toplevel()
    Home.title("The Belgium Fries Guys")
    width = 500
    height = 400
    screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
    screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()
    x = (screen_width/2) - (width/2)
    y = (screen_height/2) - (height/2)
    root.resizable(0, 0)
    Home.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (width, height, x, y))
    lbl_home = Label(Home, text="Register New Cashier:", font=('Arial', 18)).grid()
    btn_back = Button(Home, text='Back', command=Back).grid(pady=20, columnspan=3)

    lbl_username1 = Label(Home, text = "Username:", font=('arial', 14), bd=15)
    lbl_username1.grid(row=3, sticky="e")
    lbl_password1 = Label(Home, text = "Password:", font=('arial', 14), bd=15)
    lbl_password1.grid(row=4, sticky="e")
    lbl_text = Label(Home)
    username1 = Entry(Home, textvariable=username, font=(14))
    username1.grid(row=3, column=1)
    password1 = Entry(Home, textvariable=password, show="*", font=(14))
    password1.grid(row=4, column=1)

    global conn, cursor
    conn = sqlite3.connect("cashier.db")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `member` (mem_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT, username TEXT, password TEXT)")  
    cursor.execute("insert into member(username, password) values (?, ?)",(username1, password1))

    btn_register = Button(Form, text="Register", width=25, command=register)
    btn_register.grid(pady=25, row=4, columnspan=3)
    btn_register.bind('<Return>', register)
```

Comment: your code snippet seems to be incomplete

Comment: @AzatIbrakov - incomplete and incorrectly formatted (see definition of `register()`)

Comment: Read [Is this bad programming practice in tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25454065/is-this-bad-programming-practice-in-tkinter) and [Event-driven programming](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9343402/7414759)

Comment: You are using `Entry` objects (`username1`,`password1`) in `cursor.execute(...)`.  Replace them by `username.get()` and `password.get()`.

Comment: The first step in debugging this is to examine `username1` and `password1` to see if they contain the value you assume they do. Hint: they do not.