# tkinter for Python 3.X - How to I get the value of text entered into the a field to be stored as a variable?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have two buttons and a text field in a GUI. I want to input text into the text field, preferably a number, and then hit enter or a button to save that text as a variable 'Q' using Widget2 . I then want to use that value in Widget1. How do I do this?

I'm using Python 3.7

OS : Win 10

```
def Widget1():
    print("Code Not Ready")

    print("Input =", Q)

def Widget2(event):

    Q= Words_field.get()
    print("Words = ", Q)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    GUI = Tk()
    GUI.title('Widgets')
    GUI.configure(background="Grey") 
    GUI.geometry()   

    Label(GUI, text='Widget2').grid(row=1, column = 0)
    Words_field = Entry(GUI)

    Words_field.focus_set()  
    Words_field.bind("<Return>", Widget2)
    Words_field.grid(row =1, column = 1, ipadx=70)  

    B1 = Button(GUI, text=' 1. Widget1 ', fg='black', bg='Light Grey', command= Widget1, height=1, width=25) 
    B1.grid(row=0, column=0) 

    B2 = Button(GUI, text=' 2. Widget2 ', fg='black', bg='Light Grey', command= Widget2, height=1, width=25) 
    B2.grid(row=0, column=1)
GUI.mainloop()
```

Comment: Read [The Tkinter Entry Widget](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm)

Comment: @stovfl - OK so, it looks like I'm using the get() correctly, but why isn't it allowing me to use it in my other widget? (thanks for that resource by the way, super useful!)

Comment: *"use that value in Widget1"*: `Q` is `local` to `def Widget2(...`. You have to make it `global`. Read also [Is this bad programming practice in tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25454065/is-this-bad-programming-practice-in-tkinter)

Comment: THANK YOU! That worked!

Answer (score 0):

```
def Widget1():
    print("Code Not Ready")

    print("Input =", Q)

def Widget2(event):
    global Q #ADDING THIS LINE ALLOWS THE VARIABLE TO BE USED ELSEWHERE!!
    Q= Words_field.get()
    print("Words = ", Q)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    GUI = Tk()
    GUI.title('Widgets')
    GUI.configure(background="Grey") 
    GUI.geometry()   

    Label(GUI, text='Widget2').grid(row=1, column = 0)
    Words_field = Entry(GUI)

    Words_field.focus_set()  
    Words_field.bind("<Return>", Widget2)
    Words_field.grid(row =1, column = 1, ipadx=70)  

    B1 = Button(GUI, text=' 1. Widget1 ', fg='black', bg='Light Grey', command= Widget1, height=1, width=25) 
    B1.grid(row=0, column=0) 

    B2 = Button(GUI, text=' 2. Widget2 ', fg='black', bg='Light Grey', command= Widget2, height=1, width=25) 


B2.grid(row=0, column=1)
GUI.mainloop()
```