# How to create a "go back Button" on a second window with tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm doing a little "Supplementshop" with python 3.7.2 and tkinter. I want to use a "go back to the main window"-button. Because I'm creating new windows through buttons and functions, I think I can't use the `.destroy` method... After one full day of testing some codes I still did not managed to get this button. I guess, I need now some help. :D

Because the code is about 600 lines already, I just did a short version from it. Hope it's enough. Code:

```
from tkinter import *
import sys, os


class MainWindow():

    def __init__(self, master, title, size):
        self.master = master
        self.title = title
        self.size = size
        self.master.title(self.title)
        self.master.geometry(self.size)

        self.hitext = Label(self.master,
                            text="some random text,\n to change the previous text lol").pack(fill=X, pady=10)

        self.productButton = Button(self.master,
                                 text="second window",
                                    width=15,
                                    command=self.productButtonClicked).place(x=15, y=55)

        self.quitMainWindow = Button(self.master,
                                     text="exit",
                                     width=15,
                                     command=mainWindow.quit).place(x=170, y=55)

    def productButtonClicked(self):
        productWindow = Toplevel()
        productFenster = ProductMenuWindow(productWindow, "second window", "260x100")


class ProductMenuWindow():

    def __init__(self, master, title, size):
        self.master = master
        self.title = title
        self.size = size
        self.master.geometry(self.size)
        self.master.title(self.title)

        self.text = Label(self.master, text="what do you want to buy?").pack(fill=X, pady=10)

        self.gobackButton = Button(self.master,
                                   text="go back to main window",
                                   width=20,
                                   command="").place(x=55, y=50) #here should be the command for the button


if __name__ == "__main__":
    mainWindow = Tk()
    mainFenster = MainWindow(mainWindow, "root/main/first window", "300x95")
    mainWindow.mainloop()
```

If I put `command=mainWindow.quit` the mainwindow of course gets destroyed and the programm stops. So heres the point, I dont now further because `.destroy` is not working here... Also sorry for some english mistakes :P

Comment: Generally you should only call `Tk()` once in a tkinter application. One way to do what you want would be to make each "window" a subclass of `Frame` and store all of its content with that as the parent. Strongly suggest you read (and follow) the accepted answer to the question [Is this bad programming practice in tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25454065/is-this-bad-programming-practice-in-tkinter) If you do so, then you should be able to call `destroy()` and get rid of the entire window.

Comment: thanks for the quick answer yesterday. Helped me a lot! @martineau

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made some changes.

Compare my version with yours.

```
from tkinter import *
import sys, os

class MainWindow():

    def __init__(self, master, title, size):
        self.master = master
        self.title = title
        self.size = size
        self.master.title(self.title)
        self.master.geometry(self.size)

        self.hitext = Label(self.master,
                        text="some random text,\n to change the previous text lol").pack(fill=X, pady=10)

        self.productButton = Button(self.master,
                             text="second window",
                                width=15,
                                command=self.productButtonClicked).place(x=15, y=55)

        self.quitMainWindow = Button(self.master,
                                 text="exit",
                                 width=15,
                                 command=self.on_cancel).place(x=170, y=55)

    def productButtonClicked(self):
        #productWindow = Toplevel()
        obj = ProductMenuWindow(self, "second window", "260x100")
        #productFenster = ProductMenuWindow(productWindow,)

    def on_cancel(self):
        self.master.destroy()        


class ProductMenuWindow(Toplevel):

    def __init__(self, parent, title, size):
        super().__init__(name='product_main_menu')

        self.parent = parent

        self.title(title)

        self.size = size

        self.geometry(size)

        self.text = Label(self, text="what do you want to buy?").pack(fill=X, pady=10)

        self.gobackButton = Button(self,
                               text="go back to main window",
                               width=20,
                               command=self.on_cancel).place(x=55, y=50) #here should be the command for the button

    def on_cancel(self):
        self.destroy()

 if __name__ == "__main__":
    mainWindow = Tk()
    mainFenster = MainWindow(mainWindow, "root/main/first window", "300x95")
    mainWindow.mainloop()
```

p.s.

`super().__init__(name='product_main_menu')`

It's used to have singleton on your `ProductMenuWindow`.

If you write `super().__init__()` you see that you could open more then one window.

Comment: thanks for the changes. I really appreciate it and using this code from you know. Thanks a lot sir.

Comment: from you now...*

Comment: Suggest you rename the variable `mainWindow` to `root`, which is what it is commonly named in tlinter apps. After doing that, then you can change `mainFenster` to  `mainWindow` — which makes more sense (to non-German speakers) in my opinion.

Comment: I totally agree with you. I'll remember it, for the next time. :)