# How to pass a entry field value to a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, parameter-passing

I am trying to make a GUI based encryption program using `tkinter` on `python3`. Here one option is to encrypt an Image now there is an entry field where the user will enter the mode, 1 for RGB and 0 for greyscale. Now I am trying to pass that entry field value to the encrypt and decrypt function which will execute upon pressing the corresponding button. But I am getting an error while I am passing the value to the function. The script where the buttons and the entry field is written, as follows:

```
global mode

def getvalue():
    mode =int(mode_txt.get()) 
    return mode


image_window = Tk()
image_window.geometry ( '350x200' )
image_window.title ('Image Cryptography')
lbl1 = Label(image_window, text = "Select mode(0 for greyscale/ 1 for RGB): " ).place( x=20, y=40 )
mode_txt = IntVar
mode_txt = Entry(image_window, width = 4) #the entry field 
mode_txt.place(x= 300, y=40)
mode_txt.bind('<Return>', getvalue)
mode_txt.pack()
```

Now I am passing the `mode` like this:

```
def encrypt():

    mode = getvalue()   
    if(mode == 0): #greyscale
    #some code#
```

The buttons are like this:

```
btn_decrypt = Button( image_window, text = "Image Decryption", command = decrypt)
btn_decrypt.place( x=20, y=100 )
btn_encrypt = Button( image_window, text = "Image Encryption", command = encrypt)
btn_encrypt.place( x=200, y=100 )
btn_exit = Button( image_window, text = "Go Back" , command = goback).place( x=140, y=150 )
image_window.mainloop()
```

The error I am getting is:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "image1.py", line 98, in decrypt
    if(mode == 0):
NameError: name 'mode' is not defined
```

I don't know where I'm am going wrong? Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What error are you getting?  Also, please try to reduce this to a [mcve] - a form which pops up a message box displaying "RGB" or "greyscale" on pressing the "doit" button would be ideal

Comment: Declaring `global mode` doesn't do anything at the module-level (it's already going to be global because of where it's placed). You should put `global mode` in all function/methods that modify it value. This isn't required to just access its current value.

Comment: The error is `in decrypt`. [Edit] your Question and show `def decrypt():`

Comment: `def decrypt():` is same as `encrypt()`

Comment: @Dutta: *"is same as encrypt()"*: So, follow the advice of @ matineau. Or change accordingly [Is this bad programming practice in tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25454065/is-this-bad-programming-practice-in-tkinter)