# How to fix tkinter issue in python?

Tags: python, tkinter, dice

I need help on figuring out why this doesn't work, I am trying to program a dice rolling app that works through graphical user interfaces in tkinter

This is for a dice rolling app that has inputs/outputs through tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import time

rolls = 1
master = Tk()
logo = PhotoImage(file="dice.gif")
Label(master, image=logo).grid(row=0)
Label(master, text="How many dice do you have?").grid(row=1)
Label(master, text="How many sides do you have?").grid(row=2)
dicenum_entry = int(dicenum.get())
dicenum_entry.grid(row=1, column=1)
sidenum_entry = int(sidenum.get())
sidenum_entry.grid(row=2, column=1)
Button(master, text='Enter', command=master.destroy).grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W, pady=4)
mainloop()

min = 1

def dice_result():
    random.randint(min, sidenum_entry)

def dice_roll():
    master= Tk()
    count = 0
    while count < dicenum_entry:
        count = count + 1
        Label(master, text="Rolling the dice(s)...").grid(row=0)
        time.sleep(2)
        Label(master, text="The values are...").grid(row=1)
        Label(master, command=dice_result).grid(row=2)
        mainloop()

def question():
    master = Tk()
    Label(master, text="Do you want to roll the dice?").grid(row=0)
    yes = Button(master, text="Yes", command=dice_roll).grid(row=1)
    no = Button(master, text="No", command=master.destroy).grid(row=2)
    mainloop()

question()
```

I get this error when it is ran:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:\Computing\Tony\Dice Roller\dice_roller2.py", line 11, in 
    dicenum_entry = int(dicenum.get())
NameError: name 'dicenum' is not defined

Comment: `dicenum` is a Widget (Entry). You have to read the value of the Entry, i.e. `entry_value = int(dicenum.get())`, in order to compare it with an int.

Comment: The error message gives the problem. You are comparing `count` (an integer) with `dicenum` (an Entry) and this isn't possible. I imagine you want to get the value of the Entry so something like `if count < int(dicenum.get()):`.

Comment: Also have a look at `EntryVar`s. They can help with the data binding.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I have updated the code, what is wrong with it now?

Comment: @NathanHewitt: ***"what is wrong"***: Change `dicenum_entry = int(dicenum.get())` to `dicenum_entry = Entry(master)` and `if count < int(dicenum_entry.get()):`. Read also [Is this bad programming practice in tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25454065/is-this-bad-programming-practice-in-tkinter)