# .get() showing null values in onclick of button

Tags: python, function, tkinter

I am trying to build a program which takes the entries from users and pass on to database (I am using wamp server). But while submitting the values there is only one set of data getting submitted i.e (0,'',0) only none values.

I have tried looking for solutions on the internet but it stood of no use.

[The entries received are 0, and ''](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CuN3b.png)

```
    from tkinter import *
    import mysql.connector as conn
    from mysql.connector import Error
    import sys
    import os

    def window():
    root = Tk()
    root.minsize(500,500)
    root.title("Product Entry Form")

    label_0 = Label(root, text="Product Entry Form",width=20,font=("bold", 20))
    label_0.pack()
    label_0.place(x=90,y=53)

    label_1 = Label(root, text="Product_id",width=20,font=("bold", 10))
    label_1.pack()
    label_1.place(x=80,y=130)
    entry_1 = Entry(root)
    entry_1.pack()
    entry_1.place(x=240,y=130)

    label_2 = Label(root, text="Product_name",width=20,font=("bold", 10))
    label_2.pack()
    label_2.place(x=68,y=180)
    entry_2 = Entry(root)
    entry_2.pack()
    entry_2.place(x=240,y=180)

    label_3 = Label(root, text="Total_Count",width=20,font=("bold", 10))
    label_3.pack()
    label_3.place(x=70,y=230)
    entry_3 = Entry(root)
    entry_3.pack()
    entry_3.place(x=240,y=230)

    Button(root, text='Submit',width=20,bg='brown',fg='white', command = 
    database).place(x=180,y=380)
    root.mainloop()

    def database():
    global Product_id
    global Product_name
    global Total_Count

    Product_id = IntVar()
    Product_name = StringVar()
    Total_Count = IntVar()

    id=Product_id.get()
    name=Product_name.get()
    count=Total_Count.get()
    con = conn.connect(
    host = "localhost",
    user = "root",
    passwd = "",
    database = "Sales_Management"
    )
    sql = "INSERT INTO Product_data (Product_id, Product_name, 
    Total_Count) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)"
    values = (id,name,count)
    print(values)
    cursor=con.cursor()
    cursor.execute(sql,values)
    con.commit()

    window()
```

Instead, I want actual entries to be displayed in the table of database

Comment: ***"data getting submitted i.e `(0,'',0)` "***: You have to connect your `*Var()` functions to the according `Entry(..., textvariable=)`. Read [The Tkinter Entry Widget](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm) and [Is this bad programming practice in tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25454065/is-this-bad-programming-practice-in-tkinter)

Comment: Please fix the indentation in your code. It's impossible to understand your code as it is currently written.

Comment: if you don't use your `*Var()` in `Entry` then get value directly from `Entry` - ie. `id = entry_1.get()`

Comment: ok, I figured it out. I was forgetting something very silly