# tkinter：2 windows pop up at the same time

Tags: python, tkinter

As a beginner, I am not familiar with tkinter and I don't know how to improve the following codes which are supposed to function like this:
After running the renamer_v.py file, a window will pop up. It displays a short description at the top and beneath it there is an orange colored buttion 'Click Me'. Click the button and then pop up the second window to select a folder. All titles of files in the folder except the hidden ones and subfolders will be given a serialized prefix.

The problem is that the main window and the second widnow pop up at the same time. Howver, the latter is designed to appear after users clicked the button.

Here is my souce code.
renamer_V1.py:

```
import win32file
import win32con
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Button
from clicked import Clicked

root=tk.Tk()
root.geometry("550x200")
label=tk.Label(root,font=("Arial Bold",15),
              text='Please select a directory to rename files in the folder:')
label.pack()
c=Clicked()
btn=Button(root,font=("Arial",15),bg='orange',text="Click Me",command=c.clicked)
btn.pack()

c.clicked()
file_lists=os.listdir(c.file_path)
n=0

for file in file_lists.copy():
    oldname=c.file_path+os.sep+file
    file_flag=win32file.GetFileAttributesW(oldname)
    is_hiden=file_flag & win32con.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN

    if os.path.isdir(oldname) or is_hiden:
        continue
    else:
        oldname=c.file_path+os.sep+file
        newname=c.file_path+os.sep+'('+str(n+1)+')'+file
        os.rename(oldname,newname)
        n+=1
label=tk.Label(root,text=str(n)+' file(s) renamed.')
label.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

clicked.py:

```
from tkinter import filedialog

class Clicked:
    file_path=None

    def __init__(self):
        print()    

    def clicked(self):
        self.file_path=filedialog.askdirectory(title='ReNamer')
```

Comment: It is because you have called `c.clicked()` after creating `btn`.

Comment: @acw1668: If I delete `c.clicked()` and run again, it hints:TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'

Comment: You should put the code block between `btn.pack()` and `label=tk.Label(..)` into a function and then assign this function to `command` option of `btn`.

Comment: @acw1668 Thx a lot. I will try your suggestion.

Comment: @kafka: Read [Is this bad programming practice in tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25454065/is-this-bad-programming-practice-in-tkinter)

Comment: @stovfl Thank you. I will read it later.

Answer (score 0):

The application is completed and now it is working perfectly under MacOS as desired. Here is the code:

```
import os
from tkinter import filedialog
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Button

root=tk.Tk()
class ReName():
    def __init__(self):
        self.n = 0
        self.label1=tk.Label(root)

    def rename(self):
        file_path = filedialog.askdirectory(title='ReNamer')
        self.file_lists = os.listdir(file_path)
        for self.file in self.file_lists.copy():
            self.oldname = file_path + os.sep + self.file
            if os.path.isdir(self.oldname) or self.file.startswith('.'):
                continue
            else:
                self.newname = file_path + os.sep + '(' + str(self.n + 1) + ')' + self.file
                os.rename(self.oldname, self.newname)
                self.n+=1
        self.label1.config(text='{} file(s) renamed'.format(self.n))
        self.label1.pack()
        btn.config(state='disabled')

ins=ReName()
root.geometry("550x200")
label=tk.Label(root,font=("Arial Bold",15),
               text='Please select a directory to rename files in the folder:')
label.pack()
btn=Button(root,font=("Arial",15),bg='orange',text="Click Me",command=ins.rename)
btn.pack()
root.mainloop()
```