# How to fetch a value from Entry object which is in another function?

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I'd like to click a <kbd>Calculate</kbd> button and then fetch value of `e_ptName = ttk.Entry(frame, textvariable= entry_var)` which is inside of another function, `create_input_frame(container)`.

However, my button is inside function of `create_button_frame(container)` which is different from `creat_input_frame`.

Is it possible to fetch values of entry objects from different functions?

I'd like to fetch many entry inputs and then process those inputs later by clicking <kbd>Calculate</kbd> and then display at the bottom.

When entry inputs are in the same main function, it is possible to fetch them but when they are inside of different functions? How can I fetch those values of entry objects?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Frame, StringVar, ttk
from tkinter import font

def create_input_frame(container):
    frame = ttk.LabelFrame(container, text='Input')
    frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    frame.columnconfigure(1, weight=3)

    entry_var = tk.StringVar()

    l_ptName = ttk.Label(frame, text = "Patient Name", font= "Arial")
    l_ptName.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=tk.W)

    #e_ptName = ttk.Entry(frame, textvariable= glo_ptName)
    e_ptName = ttk.Entry(frame, textvariable= entry_var)
    e_ptName.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky=tk.W, ipadx=5, ipady=10)

    l_ptIdealWeight = ttk.Label(frame, text='Ideal Weight', font = 'Arial')
    l_ptIdealWeight.grid(column=0, row=3, sticky=tk.W)

    e_ptIdealWeight = ttk.Entry(frame)
    e_ptIdealWeight.grid(column=1, row=3, sticky=tk.W)


    return frame

def printClick():
    pass

**def calClick():
    #I want to fetch the value from "e_ptName = ttk.Entry(frame, textvariable= entry_var)""
    # I want to test, if e_ptName is empty, pop up a window to ask for a name
    # Also, i want to fetch the value of e_ptIdealWeidht. Hence i can caluculate in this function of calClick()
    pass**
    
def create_button_frame(container):
    frame = ttk.Frame(container)

    #frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    #frame.columnconfigure(1, weight=2)

    #tk.Button(frame, text = "Calculate !", padx=50, pady=10, command=calClick, fg="blue", bg='yellow' ).grid(column=0, row=0)
    b_CalButton = ttk.Button(frame, text = "Calculate !", command=calClick)
    b_CalButton.grid(column=0, row=0)
    b_Print = ttk.Button(frame, text ='Print !', command=printClick)
    b_Print.grid(column=1, row=0)
#    b_Print.place(x=600, y=100)

    return frame

def create_output_frame(container):
    frame = ttk.LabelFrame(container, text='Reference')

  
    return frame

def create_main_window():

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title('Dexmedetomidine - Precedex')
    root.geometry('800x600')
    root.resizable(0,0)
    root.attributes('-toolwindow', True)

    
    root.text1 = tk.StringVar()

    # root.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
    # root.columnconfigure(1, weight = 4)
    root.rowconfigure(0, weight=2)
    root.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
    root.rowconfigure(2, weight=5)

    input_frame = create_input_frame(root)
    input_frame.grid(column=0, row=0)
    
    button_frame = create_button_frame(root)
    button_frame.grid(column=0, row=1)

    output_frame = create_output_frame(root)
    output_frame.grid(column=0, row=2)

    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    create_main_window()
```

Comment: You can't reference `Entry` objects that were created inside of separate function unless you make them `global` variables or pass them as arguments from one function to another. However the much better way to do this is to define classes and make them attributes of instances of the class and make all the function class methods — that way they can be reference in any method via i.e. `self.e_ptName`.

Comment: See accepted answer to [Is this bad programming practice in tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25454065/is-this-bad-programming-practice-in-tkinter) for information about using classes with examples.